# Does inets support CGI?

Tags: erlang, inets

YAWS can run an old CGI application written using python perfectly. However, I still want to know whether or not inets supports CGI ?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you search for CGI in this PDF, you'll find information on it. I haven't tried it, but yes, CGI scripts should work.

http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/inets.pdf